# Locking an Access table to prevent writes at certain times

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am doing a weekly forecast in which people will have a template in Excel to enter data into.  Once they enter all of their data they click a button in Excel that puts the data into a table in the Access database.

On Fridays at 10:30AM I want to make the table locked so that there is a hard deadline for people to get data into the database.  At that point that week forecast is final and then I would like the database to be able to be written to again (not locked anymore) after say 5PM on Friday.

Is this possible?  Even if there could be a separate button that I could click myself at 10:30 AM that would lock the table and then I could click it again at 5PM to make it unlock the table (or a separate button for that too).  Also How would I be able to make a message box that only comes up when the table is locked to tell the users that the deadline has occurred and there is no more writing to the table?

The code that I have for injecting the data into the Access database table from the Excel template is:

```
 Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()

 If MsgBox("This Button Will Submit all Data in the Table to the Right & Clear the Table! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub


 ' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
 ' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
    "Data Source=DatabasePath;"
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "Forecast_Items", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdTable
' all records in a table
On Error GoTo transerror

cn.BeginTrans
r = 17 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Len(Range("D" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column D table
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("UserName") = Range("B" & r).Value
        .Fields("Forecast_Date") = Range("C" & r).Value
        .Fields("Area") = Range("D" & r).Value
        .Fields("Description_Item") = Range("E" & r).Value
        .Fields("Account") = Range("F" & r).Value
        .Fields("RRDD") = Range("G" & r).Value
        .Fields("CostCenter") = Range("H" & r).Value
        .Fields("Fleet") = Range("I" & r).Value
        .Fields("ForecastAmount") = Range("J" & r).Value
        .Fields("PlanAmount") = Range("K" & r).Value
        .Fields("VarianceForecast") = Range("L" & r).Value
        .Fields("Explanation") = Range("M" & r).Value



        ' add more fields if necessary...

    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.UpdateBatch 'injects full table from excel into access at the same time, eliminating possible errors with inserting certain rows over others
cn.CommitTrans 'makes sure that there were no errors before sending off all of the data
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

MsgBox ("Data was Submitted Successfully! A copy of your submitted data is on tab Submitted Information")
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
     Sheets("Forecast Form").Select
Range("B16:M100").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Submitted Information").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
     Sheets("Forecast Form").Protect Password:="password", DrawingObjects:=False, AllowFormattingCells:=True
     Sheets("Forecast Form").Range("D17:M100").ClearContents
        Exit Sub
       transerror:
    cn.RollbackTrans
     rs.Close
     Set rs = Nothing
     cn.Close
     Set cn = Nothing
      MsgBox ("Required Fields are: Area/Description Item/Fleet (Use Drop Down Box to Find Appropriate Naming or N/A)/Forecast Amt/Plan Amt/Variance Amt/Explanation."), , "Data Input Error"
     MsgBox ("Data Was Not Submitted"), , "Data Input Error"

      End Sub
```

Comment: I would create something like an 'Admin' table in Access; then add a record like 'Lock Status'; then build your mechanism to set a 'lock' or 'unlocked/ status in that record (and maybe also have message text). Next, add a startup macro to Excel that checks the lock status, displays the message if locked. Your 'ADOFromExcelToAccess' code in Excel would also need to check the lock status (in case someone left the app open all night).

Answer (score 2):

As for the issue of Locking the table, have a form opened in Access, with a [Timer event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192530.aspx) check for the day and time to lock and unlock.
Lock using a Transaction on the table:

```
Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
CurrentDB.Execute "Update MyTable SET MyField=MyField & ''"
```

And unlock by rolling back this Transaction:

```
Workspaces(0).Rollback
```

This can be implemented in Access without changing the Excel code, updating a locked table will cause an error.

If the timer event gets it's lock and unlock times from a table in Access, the error handler in Excel can create a link to this table, and check if the lock is implemented because of the time, or it is some other error... based on this you can create your message.

Comment: +1 for creativity... although I don't think I would want my table to stay in this locked state for half a day. Just a gut feeling.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are currently using the old Jet.OLEDB provider, but if you ever upgrade your database file to .accdb for Access 2010 or later (and use ACE.OLEDB or ACE ODBC) then you could create a Before Change [data macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) to lock the table:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

Answer (score 1):

`.OpenRecordSet` has a `dbDenyWrite` parameter. I'm not sure if it applies in this case, but it might get you on the right path. As for time intervals, there is another question that may help in writing rules on when to lock the table automatically. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782256/code-to-run-macro-on-time-interval)

Wayne's comment about an admin table to store the current lock status would allow you to make the message box.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you are opening a table using a DAO recordset in code:
CODE

Set r = CurrentDB.OpenReocrdset(SomeTable, dbOpenTable , dbDenyRead)

Just run this simple script using Windows Task scheduler .  Here is a link that describes how to schedule a task.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7